# calculation of Width for bold string

Tags: mfc

Can anyone help to me.I want to calculate width for bold string..I have calculated by using this code,but it is giving more pixels(7 pixels extra).

How can i reduce these pixels.

Example: I am having Bold String 'Intermediatery Bank:'.When i execute this code i am getting 147 pixels..but it is giving more(7 pixels extra).

```
int CPrintableInvoice::GetFormattedStringWidth(const CString& txt)
{
      if (txt.IsEmpty())
      return 0;

      CFont *pOldF, *pF = GetFont();
      CClientDC dc(this);
      LOGFONT lf;
      memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
      lf.lfWeight =FW_BOLD ;
      CFont newFont;
      VERIFY(newFont.CreatePointFontIndirect(&lf, &dc));
      pOldF = dc.SelectObject(&newFont);
      CRect r;
      dc.DrawText(txt, &r, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CALCRECT);
      int wid = r.Width();
      dc.SelectObject(pOldF);
      return wid;
}
```

Please help me,I am new to MFC.

Thanks,
Hareesh

Comment: There was no reason to create another question. Your `LOGFONT lf` variable is undefined. You were supposed to populate it using GetLogFont() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcs623h.aspx function. After your memset() call pF->GetLogFont(&lf);

Comment: Thanks for the reply...But i am not getting any errors.. if LOGFONT lf variable is undefined,then i need to get errors....right.

Comment: the variable is defined. I should have used the correct term. The "Font name" and "size" variables are not populated. When you use GetLogFont(&lf), all the parameters of the lf structure will be populated from the font used in your DC. After you change the Weight the boldness will be changed, and the `newFont` will be created as the input font, but Bold

Comment: I have followed the code by this link http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/beeson/courses/cs130/LectureNotes/20-Fonts2/Fonts2.html..ok i will modify the code in this way.

Comment: int CPrintableInvoice::GetFormattedStringWidth(const CString& txt)
{
      if (txt.IsEmpty())
      return 0;

      CFont *pOldF, *pF = GetFont();
      CClientDC dc(this);
      LOGFONT lf;
      memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));                           pF->GetLogFont(&lf)                             
      lf.lfWeight =FW_BOLD ;
      CFont newFont;
      VERIFY(newFont.CreatePointFontIndirect(&lf, &dc));
      pOldF = dc.SelectObject(&newFont);
      CRect r;
      dc.DrawText(txt, &r, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CALCRECT);
      int wid = r.Width();
      dc.SelectObject(pOldF);
      return wid;
}

Comment: I can't open the link. Perhaps it is your university intranet link. Anyway, use debugger, you will see that after your memset line all the members of the lf structure will be empty. When you create a new font it will be created I guess as a default font that Windows thinks is the default. It will be not the font current on your DC

Comment: If it is what they teach you at the university then it is incorrect. Use debugger

Comment: You need to add `pF->GetObject(&lf)` before setting the bold attribute

Comment: After memset().I call pF->GetLogFont(&lf);,my exe is crashing.Can any one please help.

Comment: Can any one help in this please..

Answer (score 0):

Try to call:

CSize txtSize = dc.GetTextExtent(txt);

after

pOldF = dc.SelectObject(&newFont);

Hope it helps,

Vinicius